# Is there anyway to color `git push` output?

Tags: git, colors, zsh

I've tried using:

- stderred, https://github.com/sickill/stderred
- colors in git, http://scie.nti.st/2007/5/2/colors-in-git
- global config `color.ui=true`.

Though the output from git push on error is all white. Everything in my ZSH is colored and this looks ugly & becomes harder to parse as everything else has color.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, but it looks like support for this just isn't built in to git at the moment...  Comparing this:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/push.c

with this:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/log.c

You'll see that the latter has various references to color (starting with including `color.h`), and the former does not.  That could be a starting point for you or someone to modify the git source (and submit a pull request or similar) to have this functionality.

I'm not sure why you're not having success with stderred, though; `git push` does, I've just confirmed, send its output to stream 2 (stderr), so it seems like it ought to work, provided that it's working for other utilities.